# Marcar múltiples días DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Necesito hacer una selección de múltiples días en un `DatePicker`. Ya he conseguido guardar el valor de los días clicados, pero no consigo que se queden marcados en el `DatePicker` aquellos días que he seleccionado.

```
public class DataPickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
  ArrayList<DatePicker> array = new ArrayList<DatePicker>();
  DatePickerDialog t;
  View p;
  Drawable drawable;
  DataPickerFragment yo;
  TextView text;
  Hashtable<String, String> datesselected;
  ArrayList<View> arr;
  int month;
  int year;
  int day;
  private Object callback;
  private static float BOTTOM_DATES = 200;
  //private OnDayClickListener c;
  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //Use the current time as the default values for the time picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    if( callback instanceof UserForm) {
      c.add(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, 0);
      c.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
      c.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 20);
    }
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    datesselected = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    Resources res = getResources();
    BOTTOM_DATES = res.getDimension(R.dimen.botom_dates);
    arr = new ArrayList<View>();
    t = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, day, month,year);
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(t.getContext());
    p = li.inflate(R.layout.pincho, null);
    p.setY(BOTTOM_DATES);
    text = (TextView) p.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    //t.getDatePicker().getOnFocusChangeListener().onFocusChange();

    t.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){

      @Override
      public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        if( callback instanceof CreateEvent) {
            t.addContentView(p, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(t.getDatePicker().getWidth(), t.getDatePicker().getWidth() / 6));
            datesselected = ((CreateEvent)callback).getTablaHash();
            String dates = "";
            Enumeration keys = datesselected.keys();
          while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object key = keys.nextElement();
            dates += datesselected.get(key).toString() + "\n";
          }
          text.setText(dates);
        }
      }
      });
      t.getDatePicker().init(
        year,month,day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener(){

          @Override
          public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int years, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            if(years != year){
              month = monthOfYear+1;
              year = years;
              day = dayOfMonth;
            }else {
              month = monthOfYear+1;
              year = years;
              day = dayOfMonth;
              if (datesselected.containsKey(dayOfMonth + "-" + monthOfYear + "-" + years)) {
                datesselected.remove(dayOfMonth + "-" + monthOfYear + "-" + years);
              } else {
                datesselected.put(dayOfMonth + "-" + monthOfYear + "-" + years, dayOfMonth + "-" + month + "-" + years);
              }
              String dates = "";
              Enumeration keys = datesselected.keys();
              while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                Object key = keys.nextElement();
                dates += datesselected.get(key).toString() + "\n";
              }

              text.setText(dates);
           }
        }
      }
    );
    return t;
  }
  public void setCallback(CreateEvent callback){
    this.callback = callback;
  }
  public void setCallback(UserForm callback){
    this.callback = callback;
  }
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    if( callback instanceof CreateEvent) {
      ((CreateEvent)callback).setTablaHash(datesselected);
    }else{
      ((UserForm)callback).setDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: quieres hacer una seleccion de multiples dias en un DatePicker?

Comment: Mira este link de Stackoverflow en inglés: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738089/change-datepicker-dialog-color-for-android-5-0

Comment: @Error404 no parece que quiera cambiar solo el color. si no ir marcando los que han ido pulsando

Comment: @lois6b La verdad que no me ha quedado claro del todo lo que preguntaba. Por eso he añadido el link, por si podía ayudar :D

Comment: Hola @Arekjaar. Sería mucho mejor si nos dejaras el código que llevas hasta el momento con lo que has intentado. De esta manera, podemos enfocar mucho mejor el problema y no basándonos en suposiciones sobre cómo has hecho el código. Si agregas el código, yo no tengo ningún problema en votar para reabrir la pregunta :)

Comment: Hola @Error404 ya he puesto el código, a ver si me podéis ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: @Arekjaar Ya he votado para reabrirla :)